# QGIS record containing polygon for each lat/lon point

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv

I have two layers in QGIS. One is a shapefile of states in the US. The other is a csv with lat/lon coordinate points, with data at each point.

I want to export a csv from QGIS that has a column that records what state each data point falls in.

For example, let's say I have 4 columns in my csv file. First is location ID, second is Latitude, third is Longitude, and fourth is count (just a number). One of the rows might look like this:

123456, 41.2, -97.3, 4

Since this point is in Nebraska (in real-life and according to my shapefile), I want to have a new column for state, so that the above row would now look like this:

123456, 41.2, -97.3, 4, Nebraska

Is this something I would use 'Join Attributes by Location' for? I'm trying that now, but its suspiciously slow.

Comment: Join Attributes by Location should do it. When processing time is an issue,  reducing the file sizes by exporting a subset of features and re-trying is the first step in trouble shooting for me.  For example, you could try only 4 states and see whether that helps.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this idea. It is 80% of the way completed now, so I'll probably just wait it out this time. Thanks again.

Comment: If the state layer has many attributes, you could speed things up by eliminating the unnecessary attributes before joining.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment from @ZrSiO4:
Join Attributes by Location worked, though time-consuming!

The Join Attributes tool can be found in the top menu Vector > Data Managemtn Tools > Join Attributes by Location, and inputting the csv coordinates for the first input, and polygon shape file for the second input.